# After dismissing imagePickerController memory not being released

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm calling `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];` when user either chooses a picture from the library or cancels.
I'm also setting delegate to nil just to be sure but that doesn't help either.

Am I missing something?

```
-(void)callImagePickerDelegate:(CameraView *)sender{


UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


self.imageFromLibrary.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.imageFromLibrary.frame.origin.y, self.imageFromLibrary.frame.size.width, self.imageFromLibrary.frame.size.width);}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

[self.cameraView.session startRunning];

picker.delegate = nil;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have declared your picker as strong property that is why it is not releasing it's memory.

Declare your picker as weak property and then try .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You nil only delegate of picker not actual picker object. so set picker = nil, if you have't used ARC then also write `picker = nil;[picker release];`

Comment: But.. when dismissing the picker it automatically releases it because I'm using ARC so there's no need to set it nil... Anyhow, tried it and didn't help.